# While converting my main.py to a .apk I get an error: Error compiling Cython file:

Tags: kivy, buildozer

**Description**

I am trying to convert my Python code to an `.apk` app using buildozer (in colab) and I get an error (I have provided my code at the end of error).

**Versions**

- My Python version: 3.10.6
- my kivy version: 3.0.0
- my cython version: 3.0.0

Error:

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 178998:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
 ...
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
warning: kivy/core/image/../../lib/../include/config.pxi:2:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
...

warning: kivy/core/image/../../lib/sdl2.pxi:1073:4: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    # works only for write.
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:35:18: Cannot assign type 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1' to 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, void *, size_t, size_t) noexcept'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
    rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:36:17: Cannot assign type 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) except? -1' to 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) noexcept'


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1031, in build_arch
    self.build_cython_components(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1056, in build_cython_components
    self.cythonize_build(env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in cythonize_build
    super().cythonize_build(env, build_dir=build_dir)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1104, in cythonize_build
    self.cythonize_file(env, build_dir, join(root, filename))
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 59, in cythonize_file
    super().cythonize_file(env, build_dir, filename)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1093, in cythonize_file
    shprint(python_command, "-c"
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
warning: kivy/core/image/../../lib/../include/config.pxi:2:0: The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
...

warning: kivy/core/image/../../lib/sdl2.pxi:1073:4: The 'IF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using runtime conditions or C macros instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    # works only for write.
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:35:18: Cannot assign type 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, const void *, size_t, size_t) except? -1' to 'size_t (*)(SDL_RWops *, void *, size_t, size_t) noexcept'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef SDL_RWops *rwops = SDL_AllocRW()
    rwops.hidden.unknown.data1 = <void *>byteio
    rwops.seek = NULL
    rwops.read = NULL
    rwops.write = &rwops_bytesio_write
    rwops.close =&rwops_bytesio_close
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/core/image/_img_sdl2.pyx:36:17: Cannot assign type 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) except? -1' to 'int (*)(SDL_RWops *) noexcept'
```

This is my code:

```
import kivy
import socket
import threading
import rsa 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import mainthread


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
public_key, privet_key= rsa.newkeys(1024)


class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    server_public_key=None
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()

    @mainthread
    def update_chat_text(self, message):
        self.chat_text.text += message + "\n"   

    def send_message(self):
        client.send(rsa.encrypt(f"{self.nickname_text.text}: {self.message_text.text}".encode(), self.server_public_key))

    
    def connect_to_server(self):
        if self.nickname_text.text != "":
            client.connect((self.ip_text.text, 9999))
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if message == "NICK":
                client.send(self.nickname_text.text.encode('utf-8'))
                self.server_public_key=rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(client.recv(1024))
                client.send(public_key.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
                self.send_btn.disabled = False
                self.message_text.disabled = False
                self.connect_btn.disabled = True
                self.ip_text.disabled = True
                self.make_invisible(self.connection_grid)
                self.make_invisible(self.connect_btn)
                thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
                thread.start()

    def make_invisible(self, widget):
        widget.visible = False
        widget.size_hint_x = None
        widget.size_hint_y = None
        widget.height = 0
        widget.width = 0
        widget.text = ""
        widget.opacity = 0

    def receive(self):
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            try:
                message = rsa.decrypt(client.recv(1024), privet_key).decode()
                self.update_chat_text(message)
            except Exception as ex:
                print("ERROR:", ex)
                client.close()
                stop = True

    

class NeuralWebChat(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()

neuralWebChat = NeuralWebChat()
neuralWebChat.run()
```

I am new in kivy and coding and I am confused so much

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error with a Kivy/KivyMD app with Python 3.10.10. Using Cython <3.x has solved my problem. The problem is known: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8370.

Here a part of my requirements.txt:

```
    ...
    Cython==0.29.33
    Kivy==2.2.1
    kivymd==1.1.1
    ...
```

It might help when you delete all temporary buildozer files (in the hidden folder) and start a fresh build.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try
cd ~
sudo pip uninstall cython
sudo pip install cython==0.29.36
after that cd back into yur project directory and run
buildozer --verbose android debug

- Your Python version can be what ever: eg(3.10.6)
- Your kivy version: (2.2.1) as this is the max version available for now
  this should work cause i had the same exact error and this is what fix it for me

Answer (score -2):

How is your kivy version 3.0.0? the latest kivy version is 2.2.1
The issue here is the cython version that you're using, downgrade to a lower cython version and it should work.

Answer (score -2):

I have only created my Kivy application (Kivy==2.2.1) in Cython version **0.29.36**.
So try the following

*pip unistall cython*

then

*pip install cython==0.29.36*

Good luck

Comment: typo in `uninstall` and did not work for me